# showing continuity of a multivariate function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have a really complicated function $f(x, y)$, where $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, which I need to show is continuous **at every point** in the domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Approach:** Pick an arbitrary point $(x, y) \in D$. Fix some $\epsilon > 0$. Then, I need to show $\exists$ $\delta > 0$, such that, for all $(u, v) \in D$,  , we have $(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2 < \delta^2$ $\implies$ $|f(x, y) - f(u, v)| < \epsilon$.

Sadly, using this approach is really hard, the expression $|f(x, y) - f(u, v)|$ is too complicated to reduce to a nice form.

I think there is a result which says: "sum and product of continuous maps from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous." If so, is it good enough if I am able to write $f(x, y) = f_1(x, y) . g_1(x, y) + ... + f_n(x, y). g_n(x,y)$ for all $(x, y) \in D$ and simply show that $f_i(x, y)$ and $g_i(x,y)$ are individually continuous on the domain $D$?

Comment: Sorry, what's the expression for $f(x,y)$? It could help to receive support.

Comment: Actually, I am supposed to solve it by myself; therefore, I will keep the question more general.

Comment: This is the same as saying: how can be solve the integral $\int f(x)dx$?

Comment: no, it's not. Read the last paragraph.

Comment: You will not always be able to write a function as a sum of continuous functions (or product). It depends so much of the expression for $f(x)$.

Comment: okay, assume I can (edited above).